# What are the charging requirements for Lumia 950?

Tags: charging, lumia-950

I've had some pretty mixed luck trying to charge my Lumia 950 from various sources. Charging directly from the AC to USB adapter that came with the phone seems to be fairly reliable. But plugging into nearly anything else via the USB A to USB C adapter usually ends up being slow or not working at all.

I'm guessing this probably has something to do with the new USB Type-C connection, and varying power requirements that come with the new specification. I know there's probably some information that could be gleaned from the USB standards themselves, but we can't always trust manufacturers to adhere to those specs - and, ultimately, a device requires and can only tolerate what it's designed to use regardless of what the standards "allow".

The AC charger that came with the phone says the following about its input/output:

- Input

  - AC
  - 100-200 V
  - 50-60 Hz
  - 0.40 A
- Output

  - DC
  - 5 V
  - 3.0 A

Do I really need to get adapters that exactly meet the Output specs of the original AC adapter? Or will the Lumia 950 charge reasonably well with a weaker supply? One of the supplies I've particularly had problems with has a 1 A and 2.1 A port, and neither seems to work.

What are the minimum requirements? Are there any maximums I should refrain from exceeding?

Comment: Have you tried a USB3 port on a PC? I've certainly found *some* USB chargers do not deliver the required current

Comment: @RowlandShaw Last night, the USB 3 port on my laptop was charging it pretty slow. That could be due to issues unrelated to power delivery though. My main reason for asking this question is to ascertain what's needed for when I go to purchase additional chargers for the car and such.

Comment: No car charger under 2amp will charge for me.

Comment: I have yet to run into a charger that doesn't charge my Lumia 950 at some capacity or another.

I try to make sure they are at least 2.1 A at least, but even less amperage works, just slower...

Answer (score 1):

You can charge from 2.1 amps and up, but it will be slow unless you use at least 3 amps.

I use the Anker PowerCore because it gives me 4.8A output and charges in about 30 minutes...